# How to open popup in center of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am opening a popup after closing another popup using this code:

```
function closeDeleteFilePopup() {
  $('#overlay_form_deleteGenFile').fadeOut(100, function completefadeOutCallback() {
    $('#overlay_form_uploadGenFile').fadeIn(100);
    positionPopupForFileSection();
  });
}
```

And my positioning method is:

```
function positionPopupForFileSection() {
  var popup = $('.overlay_form:visible');
  popup.css({
    marginLeft: -(popup.outerWidth() / 2),
    top: ($(window).height() > popup.outerHeight() ? ($(window).height() - popup.outerHeight()) / 2 : 20),
    marginTop: $(window).height() / 2
  });
```

It is not opening popup in middle of screen. I just want that not regarding the scroll on page, just open the popups at exactly center of the screen.

How can I do that?

Comment: better do centering via CSS...

Comment: This question is primarily about CSS, and has nothing to do with JSP, at all.

Answer (score 0):

`marginLeft` should be the width of the window/screen devide 2 minus the width of the popup devide 2.

```
marginLeft: (window.innerWidth / 2) - (popup.outerWidth() / 2)
```

`(window.innerWidth / 2)` - the x of the popup will first position on the center of the screen

`- (popup.outerWidth() / 2)` - we subtract the width of the popup so the x will adjust and make it looks like anchored on the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css to your popup (container).

```
position: fixed; 
top: 50%; 
left: 50%; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it better with CSS, look at my solution, it's the general solution to the absolute vertical/horizontal centering, it's up to you what to use JS or CSS

```js
function positionPopupForFileSection() {
  var popup = $('.overlay_form');
  popup.css({
    'top': '50%',
    'left': '50%',
    'transform': 'translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)'
  });
}

positionPopupForFileSection();
```

```css
body {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #eee;
}
.overlay_form {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: crimson;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate3d(-50%, -50%, 0)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="overlay_form"></div>
```